# Best approach to maintain a clone of a db in Postgres RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

We'd like to maintain a separate database for our dev environment that closely resembles the current state of our production database. What is the best way to do this in RDS? Our current process is to restore the nightly snapshot of our production db and make this our dev db. The problem with this approach is that it takes ~18hrs for all the changes (e.g. going from a multi AZ instance to a single AZ instance) to take effect, and we get charged on-demand rates while transitioning. So we only get to take advantage of the reservation for the dev db for 25% of the day.

Is there a better approach to maintaining a copy of a production db in RDS? I know they have read-replicas available now, but that is not sufficient for us.

Thanks in advance!